# Will the next release of ROS 2.0 run on macOS Catalina?

Tags: ros, ros2, mac

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am beginning to explore the use of ROS 2.0 on a Mac and was wondering if the next release (Nov 2019) was planned to be compatible with Catalina?

I ask because I have struggled to get Crystal and Dashings to build successfully on Catalina so I suppose it's too new to be supported by any of these distributions.

I'm a beginner with anything ROS so any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336421/will-the-next-release-of-ros-2.0-run-on-macos-catalina?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2019-10-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not an authoritative answer, but at least according to REP 2000 (""), ROS 2 Eloquent is still only targetting Mojave: [Eloquent Elusor (November 2019 - November 2020)](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#eloquent-elusor-november-2019-november-2020).

MacOS Mojave (10.14) is listed as a "tier 1" supported OS.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2019-10-30**:
Thanks very much for the answer and the link :)

It seems counterintuitive that Eloquent will target macOS Mojave given that the latest macOS is Catalina. Is it common for ROS 2.0 distributions to work on OS versions slightly ahead of their officially intended target?

Apologies if this an amateur question!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-31**:\

> Is it common for ROS 2.0 distributions to work on OS versions slightly ahead of their officially intended target?

Are you asking whether there is a chance that building Eloquent on Catalina might still work?

If so: I would not know.